# Proof of 2^n deck of card, it will be reverse order performing n perfect in-shuffle.

Tags: permutations

I am now trying to prove performing n perfect in-shuffle with 2^n deck of card, and then it will be resulting reverse order.

For example, 
Initial : [1, 2, 3, 4]
1st round : [3, 1, 4, 2]
2nd round : [4, 3, 2, 1] = reverse order!

Until now, I realized following some information.

1. each k steps, card pair with 2^k cards are reverse order.
2. card at kth, when next shuffle, it will be at 2k mod 2^(n-1)+1

I does not know how to prove when I do n perfect in-shuffle, then I get reverse order of original deck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to verify (it looks like you almost had this) that this shuffle maps:
$$\sigma: i \rightarrow 2i \mod (2^n + 1) \textrm{ for $i \in \{1,...,2^n\}$}$$

Take $a \in \{1,...,2^n\}$:

$$\sigma^n(a) = 2^n(a) \mod (2^n + 1)$$
$$= (2^n+1)(a) - a \mod (2^n+1)$$
$$= - a \mod (2^n+1)$$
$$= 2^n+1-a$$

As $2^n+1-a$ is the mirror of the initial position of $a$, we have shown that this deck will be reversed after performing $n$ shuffles.

Comment: Yes! Fixed that - thank you for catching it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my life!